# PHP Submit Button Doesn't Send Query - Joomla 3x

Tags: php

I'm coding a custom Website Report Form for Joomla and I'm putting it in a Flexicode Insert PHP module. However the Submit button does not work and therefore it won't send the database query. I'm newish to PHP but all other submit button's I've done work fine. I've tried replacing the query with an echo statement but it doesn't even echo that. (I've just pasted the submit button part of the code) Thanks!

```
<?php
echo "<table style='text-align:center;text-align:center;margin-left:41%;'>";
echo "<tr><td><h4>Report Website Issue</h4></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><form method='post'><select name='area'  onchange='this.form.submit()'>
<option value=''>Select Website Area</option>
<option value='General'>General</option>
<option value='Emails'>Emails</option>
<option value='Education'>Education</option>
<option value='Reviews'>Reviews</option>
<option value='Store'>Store</option>
<option value='Toolkit'>Toolkit</option>
<option value='Membership'>Membership</option>
<option value='Other'>Other</option>
</select></form>
</td></tr>";
echo "<form method='post'>";
$selected = $_POST["area"];
echo "<tr><td><h5><center>Current Area Selected: $selected</center></tr></td></h5>";
if($_POST['area'] == 'General') {
    echo "<tr><td><input type='text' name='subsection' placeholder='Subsection'></td></tr> ";
}
else if($_POST['area'] == 'Emails') {
    echo "<tr><td><select name='subsection'>
    <option value=''>Select Membership Plan</option>
    <option value='Notification'>Notifications</option>
    <option value='Newsletter'>Newsletter</option>
    <option value='Store'>Store Emails</option>
    </select></td></tr>";
}
else if($_POST['area'] == 'Education') {
    echo "<tr><td><select name='subsection'>
    <option value=''>Select Subsection</option>
    <option value='Lighting'>Lighting</option>
    <option value='Sound'>Sound</option>
    <option value='Rigging'>Rigging</option>
    <option value='StageManagement'>Stage Management</option>
    <option value='ConsoleTraining'>Console Training</option>
    <option value='Tips'>Tips</option>
    </select></td></tr>";
}
else if($_POST['area'] == 'Reviews') {
    echo "<tr><td><input type='text' name='subsection' placeholder='Specific Review'></td></tr> ";
}
else if($_POST['area'] == 'Toolkit') {
    echo "<tr><td><input type='text' name='subsection' placeholder='Specific Tool'></td></tr> ";
}
else if($_POST['area'] == 'Membership') {
    echo "<tr><td><select name='subsection'>
    <option value=''>Select Membership Plan</option>
    <option value='Member'>Member</option>
    <option value='Student'>Student</option>
    <option value='Educator'>Educator</option>
    </select></td></tr>";
}
else if($_POST['area'] == 'Other') {
    echo "<tr><td><input type='text' name='subsection' placeholder='Subsection'></td></tr> ";
}
echo "<tr><td><select name='urgency'>
<option value=''>Select Urgency</option>
<option value='Minor'>Minor</option>
<option value='Serious'>Serious</option>
<option value='Urgent'>Urgent</option>
</select></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><textarea rows='6' cols='50' name='description' placeholder='Please Describe The Issue'></textarea></td></tr>";
// Submit
echo "<tr><td><center><input type='submit' name='report' value='Report Website Issue'></center></td></tr>";
echo "</form></table><hr>";
if(isset($_POST['report'])) {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $date = CURDATE();
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $area = $_POST["area"];
    $subsection = $_POST["subsection"];
    $urgency = $_POST["urgency"];
    $status = "Needs Attention";
    $who = "Needs Designation";
    $columns = array('userid', 'rdate', 'decsription', 'area', 'subsection', 'urgency', 'status', 'unset');
    $values = array($user->id, $date, $description, $area, $subsection, $urgency, $status, $who);
    $query
        ->insert($db->quoteName('#__website_issues'))
        ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
        ->values(implode(',', $values));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->execute();
    echo "Issue Successfully Reported!";
}
```

Comment: Your submit button is outside of the form. I also dont see an opening form element.

Comment: Thanks @chris85 - I've edited the code and added it above. When pressing submit, the CSS of the site disappears and it still doesn't send the query

Comment: Okay, than that is not the issue; you over simplified at first. Are there any errors in your console when you click the submit?

Comment: No errors shown on the console for this form. I've checked the Table and nothing has been added. The form is found here: [link]http://www.dev.thetechnicianstoolbox.co.uk/report

Comment: The submit button works fine there, the page submits. When you are submitting with JS the `$_POST['report']` isn't set..

Comment: Please don't use `$_POST` with Joomla. You should be using [JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) instead

Comment: The form button works but it doesn't do the query - what do you mean by when submitting with JS the $post['report'] isn't set - the submit button has the name report